# Многомерный ассоциативный массив

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Есть многомерный ассоциативный javascript массив, восстановленный из JSON такого вида:
[{"Letter":"B","FIdPackageKey":"2","FIdKodPunkta":"5"},{"Letter":"С","FIdPackageKey":"31","FIdKodPunkta":"5"},{"Letter":"E","FIdPackageKey":"28","FIdKodPunkta":"3"},{"Letter":"D","FIdPackageKey":"32","FIdKodPunkta":"3"}]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в конец этого массива добавить еще одну строчку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mass.push({Letter:'Z',...});
```

[push](http://javascript.ru/Array/push)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по структуре, которую вы написали **[{},{},...]** - это обычный массив объектов и добавить элемент в этот массив можно [таким образом](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
array.push({"Letter":"E", "FIdPackageKey":"32", "FIdKodPunkta":"3"});
```

где *array* - ваш начальный массив.